# How can I merge aggregate two dataframes in Pandas while subtracting column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a rudimentary inventory system and am having trouble finding a solution to this obstacle. I've got two Pandas dataframes, both sharing two columns: PLU and QTY. PLU acts as an item identifier, and QTY is the quantity of the item in one dataframe, while being the quantity sold in another. Here are two very simple examples of what the data looks like:

final_purch:

```
PLU               QTY
12345678          12
90123456          7
78901234          2
```

pmix_diff:

```
PLU               QTY
12345678          9
90123456          3
78901234          1
```

In this case, I'd want to find any matching PLUs and subtract the pmix_df QTY from the final_purch QTY.

In an earlier part of the project, I used aggregate functions to get rid of duplicates while summing the QTY column. It worked great, but I can't find a way to do something similar here with subtraction. I'm fairly new to Python/Pandas, so any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @Naveed Thanks so much! I've implemented it, but I'm running into a ValueError. Currently trying to cast the QTY columns to int, but it's still telling giving me an error :( "You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns."

Comment: solution was based on the data shared. it seems like the two DFs has different data type. you can use .astype('int') or astype('float') to make them the same. You post the data to make it easier to get you the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do that
Using assign and merge

```
df.assign(QTY = df['QTY'] - df.merge(df2, on='PLU', suffixes=('','_y'), how='left')['QTY_y'].fillna(0))
```

```
    PLU     QTY
0   12345678    3
1   90123456    4
2   78901234    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do:

```
df = final_purch.set_index('PLU').join(pmix_df.set_index('PLU'), lsuffix='final', rsuffix='pmix')

df['QTYdiff'] = df['QTYfinal']-df['QTYpmix']
```

output:

```
          QTYfinal  QTYpmix  QTYdiff
PLU                                 
12345678        12        9        3
90123456         7        3        4
78901234         2        1        1
```

Comment: This is giving me a keyerror about not being able to find the PLU column. I printed the dataframes and they both contain the columns, so I'm not sure what's wrong! haha

Comment: Make sure no spaces are in column names by printing `print(df.columns)`